# How to give DICOM ITK reader output as an input to an itk filter qaction button in qt?

Tags: vtk, itk

```
     MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
            QMainWindow(parent),
            ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
            {
            ui->setupUi(this);
            connect(ui->actionDICOM_Sequence, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(DICOMseq()));
            connect(ui->actionExit, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));
            connect(ui->actionCanny_2, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(canny()));
            connect(ui->actionScript_window, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(script()));
            }
        MainWindow::~MainWindow()
        {
            delete ui;
        }

        int MainWindow::DICOMseq()
        {


            typedef double InputPixelType;
```

//Pixel Type

```
const unsigned int InputDimension = 3;
```

//Dimension of image

```
typedef itk::Image< InputPixelType, 3 > InputImageType;
```

//Image Type

```
typedef itk::ImageSeriesReader< InputImageType > ReaderType;
```

//Reader of Image Type

```
ReaderType::Pointer reader = ReaderType::New();
```

//Replacement of name generator of ITK

```
 QDir dir("Dir");
                        dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(0, "  ");
                        QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);

                        std::vector<std::string> names;
                        foreach(QFileInfo finfo, list)
                        {
                            std::string str = dir.path().toStdString().c_str();
                            str = str + "/";
                            names.push_back(str + finfo.fileName().toStdString().c_str());
                        }

                        reader->SetFileNames(names);
```

//Exceptional handling

```
 try
                        {
                            reader->Update();
                        }
                        catch (itk::ExceptionObject & e)
                        {
                            std::cerr << "exception in file reader " << std::endl;
                            std::cerr << e << std::endl;
                            return EXIT_FAILURE;
                        }
```

//connector to convert ITK image data to VTK image data

```
  typedef itk::ImageToVTKImageFilter<InputImageType > ConnectorType;
                        ConnectorType::Pointer connector = ConnectorType::New();


 connector->SetInput(reader->GetOutput());

                try
                {
                    connector->Update();
                }
                catch (itk::ExceptionObject & e)
                {
                    std::cerr << "exception in file reader " << std::endl;
                    std::cerr << e << std::endl;
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }

        vtkImageData * image = vtkImageData::New();
            image->DeepCopy(connector->GetOutput());

        vtkInteractorStyleImage *style = vtkInteractorStyleImage::New();
            renderWindowInteractor1->SetInteractorStyle(style);
            viewer1->SetupInteractor(renderWindowInteractor1);
            viewer1->SetInputData(image);
            viewer1->SetSliceOrientationToXY();
            viewer1->GetRenderer()->ResetCamera();
            ui->qvtkWidget->SetRenderWindow(viewer1->GetRenderWindow());
            ui->qvtkWidget->GetRenderWindow()->Render();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }

void MainWindow::canny()
{
```

//what should i code here first to get dicom image reader output from DICOMseq() above and apply canny detection itk code//
    }

Answer (score 0):

`reader->Update();` should trigger actual reading. If not, you should first try to recreate DICOM reading following a working example, such as [this](https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/IO/DICOM/DicomSeriesReadImageWrite3/Documentation.html).

If you want to run ITK's Canny algorithm, you should skip `connector->SetInput(reader->GetOutput());` and have there instead:

```
  typedef itk::CannyEdgeDetectionImageFilter< InputImageType, InputImageType >
    FilterType;
  FilterType::Pointer filter = FilterType::New();
  filter->SetInput( reader->GetOutput() );
  filter->SetVariance( variance );
  filter->SetLowerThreshold( lowerThreshold );
  filter->SetUpperThreshold( upperThreshold );

  typedef itk::RescaleIntensityImageFilter< InputImageType, OutputImageType > RescaleType;
  RescaleType::Pointer rescaler = RescaleType::New();
  rescaler->SetInput( filter->GetOutput() );
  rescaler->SetOutputMinimum( 0 );
  rescaler->SetOutputMaximum( 255 );
  connector->SetInput(rescaler->GetOutput());
```

This code fragment is from [this example](https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Filtering/ImageFeature/DetectEdgesWithCannyFilter/Documentation.html).

If you want `canny` to be separately invoked, you should save the image which comes out of a reader into a variable of type `InputImageType::Pointer`, and have canny read and write to that variable, and update the connector after each change to it.